# How to find the mouse cursor index

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

Hi I wrote a script with the "undotext" widget,
and I'm looking for a way to get the line index of the palce where the mouse cursor is standing.

and similarly when the user has select part of the line.

Comment: I assume you mean `Tk::TextUndo`.  Do you want the mouse cursor (x,y screen coordinates) or the current position of the text cursor (column, line)?

Answer (score 2):

To get the current location of the mouse cursor in *text* coordinates (not just x,y) you need to do either this:

```
$txt->index("current");
```

or this (where `$x` and `$y` give the mouse cursor location *relative to the text widget*):

```
$txt->index("@$x,$y");
```

The first is definitely more convenient, but the second is needed if you're in the middle of a drag (the `current` mark isn't updated while any mouse button is down).